# Trouble getting Exfat formatted drive to mount

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, mount

I've just performed a new install of arch linux (3.15.3-1) on a macbook pro 8.2

All of my data is on an exfat drive, and I've installed exfat-utils. However, when
I try

```
mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 ~/drivemount
```

the return is

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

I saw a post on the arch forum mentioning doing modprobe exfat-fs, which I proceeded to try to no avail. I've looked around here, but couldn't find a post that explained it, so here I am.

Do I need some other packages, like fuse-exfat? (And why doesn't it just work with exfat-utils?)

How might I resolve this?

Answer (score 16):

I also installed just `exfat-utils` and `fuse-exfat` from the community repository but not `exfat-git'. After that mounting of an exfat usbstick worked just fine. Archlinux (3.18.5-3).

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well, but resolved it by installing the `exfat-git` package from the AUR.  After that everything simply worked. No `modprobe`, no reboot, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a kernel module for exfat to just mount, not neccesarily the tools (checking the filesystem etc).

So just install `fuse-exfat` from the `community` repo and your done without reboot or manual `modprobe` or a non-fuse exfat implementation from the `AUR` (`exfat-git` or `exfat-dkms-git`), if you know what you're doing and that it's stable enough for your use case.

Archlinux x64 from 18 Feb 2015, everything up to date with pacman / yaourt.
But generally this will stay true for the future, only some package names will change a little or new modules that implement exfat will become available.